# telnet to determine open ports (shell script)

Tags: linux, bash, telnet, rhel

I am trying to write a shell script which takes an IP address and a port number as input and outputs whether the port is open on the host.. My shell script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$(echo exit | telnet $1 $2 | grep "Connected")

if [ "$name" == "" ]
then
    echo "Port $2 is not open on $1"
else
    echo "Port $2 is open on $1"
fi
```

It works fine but my output contains 2 lines, something like this:

```
[root@ip-172-31-8-36 Scripts]# ./test.sh 172.31.35.246 7199
Connection closed by foreign host.
Port 7199 is open on 172.31.35.246
```

OR

```
[root@ip-172-31-8-36 Scripts]# ./test.sh 172.31.35.246 7200
telnet: connect to address 172.31.35.246: Connection refused
Port 7200 is not open on 172.31.35.246
```

I want to suppress the 1st line from the output in both cases.
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Why not just use the `nmap` utility?

Comment: @cdhowie our company's infra team wouldn't install nmap on the systems so I have to make do with telnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct `telnet`'s error output to `/dev/null`:

```
name=$(echo exit | telnet $1 $2 2>/dev/null | grep "Connected")
```

Comment: This is old but I wonder what is the purpose of using `echo exit` at the beginning? Shouldn't it be `echo quit` or what?

Comment: @FredrickGauss What? `exit` is a common instruction for Linux shells to terminate themselves. What makes you think `quit` would be better?

Comment: What makes me think that it would be `quit` becuase `quit` is the command for telnet after successfully connected to server. I actually didn't understand the purpose of the `echo exit` command issued at the first phase before telnet.

Comment: @FredrickGauss `quit` is a command for telnet. However, giving commands to telnet requires entering an escape code first. `exit` is for the remote shell in this case, the one executing remotely on the target server.

Comment: well, why `echo quit | ..` or `echo blabla | ..` even `echo | ..` works in this case?

Comment: @FredrickGauss telnet effectively acts as a proxy for a remote command, connecting its own standard input/output to the remote shell's. So this just passes `exit` as a command to the remote shell as soon as telnet establishes a connection. That in turn causes the remote shell to terminate, and the telnet server reacts by closing the connection, which further causes your local telnet process to terminate.

Comment: @FredrickGauss Regardless, you should be asking OP. This line of code comes directly from the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

The poor-man's `nmap` in pure bash:

```
host="127.0.0.1"
for port in {1..1024}
do
    echo "" > /dev/tcp/$host/$port && echo "Port $port is open"
done 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: @jm66 i don't see any /dev/tcp dir in linux

Comment: @c4f4t0r it is internal feature of `bash`, not real directories.

Comment: @jm666 is this a future of bash 4?

Comment: @c4f4t0r no - works on 3.2.51(1) too. Your `bash` must be compiled with `--enable-net-redirections` (but, I never saw an installation without).

Answer (score 1):

How about using [netcat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) instead?

`$ nc -v -z <host> <port>
Connection to <host> <port> port [tcp/https] succeeded!`